# svg tags(id, class) how to get rid of them and make a reusable component

Tags: svg

I have svg code drawn by designer and I want to make an reusable component from it. But that svg code is generated by some program and have a lot of Id's and classes.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" class='d-none-m'
         viewBox="0 0 800 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 30; position: absolute; bottom: 0; transform: rotateX(180deg);" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
        .st00{display:none;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        .st22{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4);filter:url(#AI_GaussianBlur_5);}
        .st33{fill:none;stroke:#E6E7E8;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<filter  id="AI_GaussianBlur_5">
    <feGaussianBlur  stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
</filter>
<line class="st00" x1="400" y1="90.7" x2="400" y2="-60.7"/>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M0,0c0,0,187.7,20,400,20S800,0,800,0H0z"/>
<g>
    <defs>
        <path id="SVGID_3" d="M400,20C187.7,20,0,0,0,0v30h800V0C800,0,612.3,20,400,20z"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_4">
            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g class="st22">
        <path class="st33" d="M400,17C187.7,17,0-3,0-3l-43.3-1.5V45l897.5-1.3V-3H800C800-3,612.3,17,400,17z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I need to get rid of id's and classes. Any help ?

Comment: Are clashing ids and classes the reason you want to do this?  What sort of reuseable component are you making?  In HTML custom components, and some other framework custom components, the SVG will be part of the shadow DOM, so there is no need to remove the ids and class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably just to change the `class` into a `style` attribute.
For example:

```
<g class="st22">
```

would become

```
<g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_4);filter:url(#AI_GaussianBlur_5);">
```

or you can convert the style properties to attributes

```
<g clip-path="url(#SVGID_4)" filter="url(#AI_GaussianBlur_5)">
```

Comment: #SVGID_4 is ID as well as #AI_GaussianBlur_5

Comment: Ok, I see.  You'll either need find or write a script to process an SVG file and rename all the classes and ids.  Or use a technique [like this one by Danny Engelman](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) that puts the SVG in the shadow DOM.